# How do I "re-group" my Series after performing an apply() on a SeriesGroupBy?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to adapt an existing function, that essentially performs a `Series.str.contains` and returns the resulting `Series`, to be able to handle `SeriesGroupBy` as input.

As suggested by the pandas error message

> Cannot access attribute 'str' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

I have tried to use `apply()` on the `SeriesGroupBy` object, which works in a way, but results in a `Series` object. I would now like to apply the same grouping as before, to this `Series`.

Original function

```py
def contains(series, expression):
    return series.str.contains(expression)
```

My attempt so far

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
... from functools import partial
...
... def _f(series, expression):
...     return series.str.contains(expression)
...
... def contains(grouped_series, expression):
...     result = grouped_series.apply(partial(_f, expression=expression))
...     return result

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(zip([1,1,2,2], ['abc', 'def', 'abq', 'bcq']), columns=['group', 'text'])
>>> gdf = df.groupby('group')

>>> gs = gdf['text']
>>> type(gs)
<class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy'>


>>> r = contains(gdf['text'], 'b')
>>> r
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: text, dtype: bool
>>> type(r)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

The desired result would by a boolean series grouped by the same indices as the original `grouped_series`.

The actual result is a `Series` object without any grouping.

EDIT / CLARIFICATION:

The initial answers make me think I didn't stress the core of the problem enough. For the sake of the question, lets assume I cannot change anything outside of the `contains(grouped_series, expression)` function.
I think I know how to solve my problem if I approach it from another angle, and if I don't that would then become another question. The real world context makes it very complicated to change code outside of that one function. So I would really appreciate suggestions that work within that constraint.

So, let me rephrase the question as follows:

**I'm looking for a function `contains(grouped_series, expression)`, so that the following code works:**

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(zip([1,1,2,2], ['abc', 'def', 'abq', 'bcq']), columns=['group', 'text'])
>>> grouped_series = contains(df.groupby('group')['text'], 'b')
>>> grouped_series.sum()
group
1    1.0
2    2.0
Name: text, dtype: float64
```

Comment: So for your example, the index should be `[0,1,0,1]`?

Comment: I don't quite understand. If your `GroupBy` aggregation returns one value per group, then the output is a Series with the group keys as the index (think `GroupBy.sum`). However, in cases where the return is one value per row within the group, then you do the calculation within group, but return a Series with the original index (think `GroupBy.cumsum`).  Your current formulation is similar to the latter, where there's really nothing group specific to the calculation.

Comment: @ALollz The thing is, that the `contains` function is not aware of the aggregation. It should simply return a `SeriesGroupBy` and then a later function will "decide" (potentially at runtime) how to aggregate the result (e.g. count all rows per group where `contains()` returned `True`). I would like to implement this without changing that flow, if possible.

Comment: @Josmoor98 Good question, I don't actually know what indices on SeriesGroupBy objects look like. (This admittedly might be partially responsible for my struggles.)

Comment: @MatthiasManhertz To my knowledge, the only thing that can return a `Series.GroupBy` is `.groupby`. At that point your only options are to `apply`, `agg` `transform` or iterate over the groups. Since your function is not aware of the grouping, there is absolutely no reason to have this be part of the groupby. You should instead define this column before grouping then create the `Series.GroupBy` object.

Comment: @ALollz I see. I was really hoping I could somehow "extract" the grouping from the `grouped_series` and then "reapply" the same grouping to the result before returning it. It seems like that should be possible, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` is not needed unless you want to do something with the "group" -- like calculating its sum or check if **all** rows in the group contain the letter `b`. When you call `apply` on a `GroupBy` object, you can pass additional argument to the function being applied by keywords:

```
def contains(frame, expression):
    return frame['text'].str.contains(expression).all()

df.groupby('group').apply(contains, expression='b')
```

Result:

```
group
1    False
2    True
dtype: bool
```

I like to think that the first parameter to the function being applied (`frame`) is a smaller view of the original dataframe, being chopped up by the `groupby` clause.

That said, `apply` is pretty slow compared to specialized aggregate functions lime `min`, `max` or `sum`. Use these as much as possible and save `apply` for complex cases.

Comment: It seems I haven't made it clear in my original question, that I cannot (do not want to) change the signature of the `contains(grouped_series, expression)` function for reasons outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I ended up accepting this answer, because it comes closest to what I actually ended up doing. For anyone actually trying to do something similar to what my question was actually about, make sure to read the comments and answer by ALollz, as they outline why the solution I was going for, just wasn't feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice of the error message, you could use `apply`:

```
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x : x.text.str.contains('b'))
Out[10]: 
group   
1      0     True
       1    False
2      2     True
       3     True
Name: text, dtype: bool
```

If you want to put these indices into your data set and return a DataFrame, use `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x : x.text.str.contains('b')).reset_index()
Out[11]: 
   group  level_1   text
0      1        0   True
1      1        1  False
2      2        2   True
3      2        3   True
```

Comment: This requires access to the original DataFrame and returns a Series. I only have access to the `SeriesGroupBy` object and am supposed to return another `SeriesGroupBy` object after performing the `.str.contains(...)` on the contents.

Answer (score 1):

`_f` has **absolutely no** relationship to the groups. The way to deal with this is to instead define a column prior to grouping (not a separate function), then group. Now that column (called `'to_sum'`) is part of your `Series.GroupBy` object.

```
df.assign(to_sum = _f(df['text'], 'b')).groupby('group').to_sum.sum()
#group
#1    1.0
#2    2.0
#Name: to_sum, dtype: float64
```

If you don't need the entire DataFrame for your subsequent operations, you can sum the Series returned by `_f` using `df` to group (as they will share the same index)

```
_f(df['text'], 'b').groupby(df['group']).sum()
```

Comment: All of this is True, but still missing the core of my question. (I take 100% of the blame for that, but am at a loss for how to make myself more clear.)
If I was in a position where I had control over the grouping and had access to the original DataFrame, this would be a fine solution (as would be the other answers), but sadly I have to work within the constraints of existing code, where I get a `SeriesGroupBy` object passed in and am supposed to return a `SeriesGroupBy` object. From your comment on the original Question this seems to not be possible though, right?

Comment: @MatthiasManhertz I don't think it's easily possible. The mantra for `groupby` is `split-apply-combine`; that is you should do all three of those. Personally, I think it's not a good idea to be passing around a `Series.GroupBy`. A `Series.GroupBy` object hasn't even split the data yet; it's **only** ensured that there's a proper mapping to the groups you want in the end. So by passing around this object, you've severely limited what you can do between function calls, and you haven't really accomplished anything.

Comment: I have accepted that what I was trying to do is not intended to be done by the pandas API. But I'm still not 100% convinced, that it is a bad idea in general. Anyway I have now gone ahead and refactored a bunch of code so that i `apply` the `contains` function to the grouped dataframe directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this. No need to do group-by

```
df['eval']= df['text'].str.contains('b')
```

`eval` is the name of the column which you want add. You can name what you want.

```
df.groupby('group')['eval'].sum()
```

Run this after the first line. The result is

```
group
1    1.0
2    2.0
```

Comment: I did try to simplify my problem in order to make it fit a Q&A format. While it is true, that your approach works in general, it won't work for me, as the input I get from a part of the code I cannot really change is already a SeriesGroupBy for reasons outside the scope of this question. I edited the original question to (hopefully) make this more clear.